# Refine nested loop to filter objects containing certain value, from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

In JavaScript, I have an array of objects:

```
var allAliases = [
  { "name": "Cards", "alias": "cards", "view": "/path/cards/" },
  { "name": "Carousel", "alias": "carousel", "view": "/path/carousel/" },
  { "name": "Image boxes", "alias": "imageBoxes", "view": "/path/imageBoxes/" },
  { "name": "Gallery", "alias": "gallery", "view": "/path/gallery/" },
  { "name": "Slide panels", "alias": "slidePanels", "view": "/path/slide-panels/" }
]
```

I then have a string array of aliases, like this:

```
var aliases = 'cards,carousel,gallery';
var permittedAliases = aliases.split(',');
```

I need to filter the original array such that I'm left with only the objects whose alias value matches and of the strings in the `permittedAliases` array.  So in the case above I'd be left with:

```
[
  { "name": "Cards", "alias": "cards", "view": "/path/cards/" },
  { "name": "Carousel", "alias": "carousel", "view": "/path/carousel/" },
  { "name": "Gallery", "alias": "gallery", "view": "/path/gallery/" }
]
```

I can do this by creating a new array, looping through the original array, comparing values and adding matched objects to the new array like this:

```
var filteredArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < allAliases.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < permittedAliases.length; j++) {
        if (allAliases[i].alias === permittedAliases[j]) {
            filteredArray.push(allAliases[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This just feels very clunky to me though, loops within loops.  I wondered if there's a neater way to do it?

The constraint is that it needs to be **ES5.1** unfortunately.

Many thanks.

Comment: *The constraint is that it needs to be ES5.1* That is not an issue. Use `Array.filter` `allAliases .filter(function(curAlias) { return aliases .indexOf(curAlias.alias) > -1 })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the array with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the aliasses.

```js
var allAliases = [{ "name": "Cards", "alias": "cards", "view": "/path/cards/" }, { "name": "Carousel", "alias": "carousel", "view": "/path/carousel/" }, { "name": "Image boxes", "alias": "imageBoxes", "view": "/path/imageBoxes/" }, { "name": "Gallery", "alias": "gallery", "view": "/path/gallery/" }, { "name": "Slide panels", "alias": "slidePanels", "view": "/path/slide-panels/" }],
    aliases = 'cards,carousel,gallery',
    permittedAliases = aliases.split(','),
    filtered = allAliases.filter(function (o) {
        return permittedAliases.some(function (a) {
            return o.alias === a;
        });
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or you could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), instead of `Array#some`

```js
var allAliases = [{ "name": "Cards", "alias": "cards", "view": "/path/cards/" }, { "name": "Carousel", "alias": "carousel", "view": "/path/carousel/" }, { "name": "Image boxes", "alias": "imageBoxes", "view": "/path/imageBoxes/" }, { "name": "Gallery", "alias": "gallery", "view": "/path/gallery/" }, { "name": "Slide panels", "alias": "slidePanels", "view": "/path/slide-panels/" }],
    aliases = 'cards,carousel,gallery',
    permittedAliases = aliases.split(','),
    filtered = allAliases.filter(function (o) {
        return permittedAliases.indexOf(o.alias) !== -1;
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I was unaware of `some` but it looks like just the job, thank you :)